# CSV Python Delimiting Underscore

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script to write to a CSV file.  Each string in the group array contains underscores (for example:  `apple_group`).  When I write to the CSV, the file looks like:

```
apple, _ ,group  
pear, _ ,group, _ ,sample
```

I need the underscores to remain as one string such as the example above.  How do I do this?

```py
f = open("output.csv", 'wt')
writer = csv.writer(f)
for item in group:
    writer.writerow((item))
f.close()
```

Comment: Please show what the array `group` looks like (can just do `print group` and paste the results)

Comment: Why the double parens? Just use `writerow(item)`, or `writerow((item,))` if you wanted a singleton tuple.

Comment: are you sure you didn't just want `writer.writerow(group)`?  writerow is expecting a sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open("output.csv", 'wt')
for item in group:
    custom_serialization = ', _ ,'.join(item.split('_')) 
    f.write(custom_serialization + '\n')
f.close()
```

Or

```
f = open('output.csv', 'w'):
    f.write('\n'.join([' _ '.join(x.split('_')) for x in group]))
f.close()
```

However, readability is preferred in Python so I'd go for the first option.